# Error when trying to overload an operator "/"

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, vector-graphics

I recently start teaching myself game programming. Someone recommend me to start with Python and I got the book "Beginning game development with Python and Pygame: From novice to professional". I got to a part where they teach about Vectors and creating a Vector2 class. Everything was going well until I tried to overload the division operator.
My code goes like this:

```
class Vector2(object):

  def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def __str__(self):
    return "(%s, %s)"%(self.x, self.y)

  @classmethod
  def from_points(cls, P1, P2):
    return cls(P2[0] - P1[0], P2[1] - P1[1])

  def __add__(self,rhs):
    return Vector2(self.x + rhs.x, self.y + rhs.y)

  def __sub__(self,rhs):
    return Vector2(self.x - rhs.x, self.y - rhs.y)

  def __mul__(self, scalar):
    return Vector2( self.x*scalar, self.y*scalar)

  def __div__(self, scalar):
    return Vector2( self.x/scalar, self.y/scalar)
```

Now, when I tried to call the "/" operator, this shows up:

```
AB = Vector2(10.0,25.0)
print(AB)   # <<<<(10.0, 25.0)
v1 = AB + Vector2(20.,10.)
print(v1)   # <<<<(30.0, 35.0)
v2 = AB - Vector2(20.,10.)
print(v2)   # <<<<(-10.0, 15.0)
v3 = AB * 3
print(v3)   # <<<<(30.0, 75.0)
print(v3 / 3)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Vector2' and 'int'
```

This was all in Python 3.3 but if I run it with Python 2.7, everything works correctly.
Where's the problem?

Comment: see http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__truediv__

Comment: I'm sure I'll get to know what is numpy. But, well, I'm trying to learn this stuff from Python. I have zero experience with it.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In Python 3.x, you need to overload the `__floordiv__` and `__truediv__` operators, not the `__div__` operator. The former corresponds to the `//` operation (returns an integer) and the latter to `/` (returns a float).

Comment: I just tested it and it works! Thanks for the answer. I'll have to do some reading on the docs.

Comment: @darkwatcher5 in python2, the result of integer division was always an integer. This means `5/2 == 2`, though `5/2.0 == 2.5`. Python3 changed that (due to the principle of least astonishment) and replaced `__div__` with `__floordiv__` (which is `5//2 == 2`) and `__truediv__` (which is `5/2 == 2.5`)

Comment: @adsmith Seems really useful to be honest. And much specific.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3, the division operators are called `__truediv__` and `__floordiv__`. See the [Data model](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__truediv__) documentation for more information.