# Have the `__rdiv__()` and `__idiv__` operators changed in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, in-place

In Python 3.x the `__div__()` operator [was deprecated in favor of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859440/error-when-trying-to-overload-an-operator) `__floordiv__()` and `__truediv__()`.

Are the `__rdiv__()` and `__idiv__()` operators still used to refer to the reversed and in-place versions of `__truediv__()`?  If so, what are the operator names for the reversed and in-place versions of `__floordiv__()`?

Comment: `_rdiv__(...)x.__rdiv__(y) <==> y/x`, did you try using them?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: @ChrisMueller: Really? Because [those names are gone](http://ideone.com/ptSWUk).

Comment: @user2357112 My mistake.  It actually doesn't work in my current code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`__rdiv__` and `__idiv__` no longer exist. The new names are the obvious choices of `__rtruediv__`, `__itruediv__`, `__rfloordiv__`, and `__ifloordiv__`, following the standard format. This is visible in the [link](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__truediv__) in the second answer on the question you linked, or by doing `dir(int)` in a Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Minor point: `__itruediv__` and `__ifloordiv__` don't show up if you do `dir(int)` because the integer class is immutable.