# What is the python3's magic method for Division?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, division

What is the python3's magic method for Division?

In most websites it is stated that `__div__` is the magic method for division but `__div__` doesn't work. What's the magic method for Division then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344025/have-the-rdiv-and-idiv-operators-changed-in-python-3-x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have the \`\_\_rdiv\_\_()\` and \`\_\_idiv\_\_\` operators changed in Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344025/have-the-rdiv-and-idiv-operators-changed-in-python-3-x)

Comment: @Tupteq No, the answer by BlackBear helped me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=iadd#emulating-numeric-types): `__truediv__`. You also have `__floordiv__` for `//`.

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer you are welcome