# Error when trying to redefine the division operator with __div__

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Why does numpy throw an exception for the following code? `foo/3` works fine.

```
import numpy as np

class item(object):
    def __init__(self, val = 0.0):
        self._val = val
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._val
    def __add__(self, other):
        return item(self.value + other.value)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return item(self.value - other.value)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, item):
            return self.value * other.value
        if isinstance(other, (int, float, long)):
            return item(other*self.value)
        raise TypeError("unsupported operand")
    def __div__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float, long)):
            return item(self.value/other)
        raise TypeError("unsupported operand")
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if self.value < other.value:
            return -1
        if self.value == other.value:
            return 0
        return 1
    def __str__(self):
        return "item <%f>" % self.value


data = [ item(x) for x in np.random.random(size = 1000) ]

foo = item(3.1)

foo/3

np.mean(data)
```

error message:

```
     45 foo/3
     46 
---> 47 np.mean(data)
     48 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyc in mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)    2714     2715     return
_methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 2716                             out=out, keepdims=keepdims)    2717     2718 def std(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, ddof=0, keepdims=False):

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.pyc in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     67         ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
     68     else:
---> 69         ret = ret / rcount
     70 
     71     return ret

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'item' and 'int'
```

Comment: Works for me on python2.7. On python3 it gives me the error you mentioned, which is due to the fact that you have to use `__floordiv__` and `__truediv__` instead of `__div__`. See for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21859568/4063051). Are you sure you are using python 2.7? What is the output you get evaluating `2/3`?

Comment: the expression `(item(2)/3).value` returns 0.

Comment: I guess numpy is using `__future__.division`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to define `__truediv__`. The documentation says:

> object.`__div__`(self, other)
>
> object.`__truediv__`(self, other)
>
> The division operator (/) is implemented by these methods. The
>   `__truediv__()` method is used when `__future__.division` is in effect, otherwise `__div__()` is used. If only one of these two methods is
>   defined, the object will not support division in the alternate
>   context; TypeError will be raised instead.

see [https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=**len**#object.**truediv**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__len__#object.__truediv__)