# In Python 3.x, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'complex' and 'complex'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the code to compute mathematical operations in Python, but this code is throwing an error.

```
    from math import power
        class complex:
            def __init__(self, real, imag):
                self.real = real
                self.imag = imag
            def __add__(self, other):
                return complex(self.real+other.real, self.imag+other.imag)
            def __sub__(self, other):
                return complex(self.real-other.real, self.imag-other.imag)
            def __mul__(self, other):
                return complex(self.real*other.real self.imag*other.imag, self.real*other.imag+self.imag*other.real)
            def __div__(self, other):
                try: 
                    return self.__mul__(complex(other.real, -1*other.imag)).__mul__(complex(1.0/(other.mod().real)**2, 0))
                except Exception as e: //Here is nothing
                    print(e)  //Here is nothing
                    return None  //Here is nothing
            def mod(self):
                return pow(self.real**2+self.imag**2, 0.5)
            def __str__(self, precision=2):
                return str(("%."+"%df"%precision)%float(self.real))+('+' if self.imag>=0 else '-')+str(("%."+"%df"%precision)%float(abs(self.imag)))+'i'

print("Enter real and imaginary part of complex No - 1(separeated by space)") 
A = complex(*map(float, input().strip().split()))
print("Enter real and imaginary part of complex No - 2(separeated by space)") 
B = complex(*map(float, input().strip().split()))

print("Addition: " + str(A+B))
print("Subtraction: " + str(A-B))
print("Multiplication: " + str(A*B))
print("Division: "+ str(A/B)) //There is an error
print("Modulas of complex Number A: " + str(A.mod()))
print("Modulas of complex Number B: " + str(B.mod()))
```

---

The error it is throwing is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Assignment_2.py", line 31, in <module>
    print("Division: "+ str(A/B))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'complex' and 'complex'
```

Comment: `__div__` is for Python 2, not Python 3 - see the other post I pointed to.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859440/error-when-trying-to-overload-an-operator